# angularjs When I refresh my page it redirects me to login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi after setting up Spring Security, the login works fin for me.But when I refresh anypage it redirects me to login page. How Can I get rid of this.
Here is my code

config.js

```
 'use strict';
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute',
        'myAppControllers', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies' ]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/products/:idCat', {
        templateUrl : '../views/partials/products.html',
        controller : 'ProductsController'

    }).when('/products', {
        templateUrl : '../views/partials/allProducts.html',
        controller : 'ProductsController'

    }).when('/supprimer', {
        templateUrl : '../views/partials/delete.html',

    }).when('/update', {
        templateUrl : '../views/partials/update.html',
        controller : 'UserController'

    }).when('/client', {
        templateUrl : '../views/partials/client.html',
        controller : 'ClientController'
    }).when('/agences', {
        templateUrl : '../views/partials/agences.html',
        controller : 'MapController'

    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : '../views/partials/login.html',
        controller : 'mainController'
    }).when('/', {
        templateUrl : '../views/partials/Home.html',
    })
    $routeProvider.otherwise('/');

});
app.run(function($route, $rootScope, $http, $location, $cookieStore,
        $anchorScroll) {
    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        var originalPath = $location.url();
        if ($rootScope.authenticated == false) {
            $location.path('/login');

        } else {
            $rootScope.redirectUrl = angular.copy($location.url());
            var user = $cookieStore.get('user');
            if (user !== undefined) {
                $rootScope.user = user;
                $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = user.token;
                $location.url(originalPath);}})
});
```

my app.js where I have my controller ang call for authenticate Service

```
myAppControllers
        .controller(
                'mainController',
                function($scope, $rootScope, loginService, ProductService,
                        $location, $cookies, $cookieStore, $http) {
                    $rootScope.salesAgent = true;
                    $scope.loggedIn = false;
                    $rootScope.hasRole = function(role) {

                        if ($rootScope.user === undefined) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        if ($rootScope.user.authorities === undefined) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.user.authorities.length; i++) {
                            if ($rootScope.user.authorities[i].authority == role)
                                return true;
                        }

                        return false;
                    };

                    $scope.logout = function() {

                        console.log("Testtttttttttt");
                        delete $rootScope.user;
                        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'];
                        $cookieStore.remove('user');
                        $location.url("/login");
                    };

                    $scope.authenticate = function() {
                                loginService
                                        .authenticate($scope.username,
                                                $scope.password)
                                        .then(
                                                function(user) {

                                                    $rootScope.user = user;
                                                    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = user.token;
                                                    $cookieStore.put('user',
                                                            user);

                                                    if ($rootScope.redirectUrl != null
                                                            && $rootScope.redirectUrl
                                                                    .indexOf('/') == -1)
                                                        $location
                                                                .url($rootScope.redirectUrl);
                                                    else {
                                                        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                                                        $location.path("/");
                                                    }
                                                    $rootScope.redirectUrl = null;
                                                    $rootScope.redirectStatus = null;
                                                }),
                                function err(data) {
                                    if ($rootScope.redirectStatus == 401)
                                        }
                    };});
```

I'll be pleased for your help!

Comment: It looks like your user info is stored into `$rootScope`. If you refresh your page, it is now emptied.

Comment: also, why do you do `$rootScope.authenticated = false;` inside your `app.run()`?

Comment: I ommited it and I putted it in my controller once the login is made successfuly but always the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing authenticated value in $rootScope after refreshing it is getting nullified, instead of that use $cookieStore for angular 1.2 or less, or $cookies for angular 1.2 or above.
You are using $cookieStore for user, do the same for authenticated

```
$cookieStore.put('authenticated',$rootScope.authenticated);
```

Comment: Still the same  problem once I refresh the  variable $rootScope.authenticated  is initialed to false. I din t know where should I initialise it !

Answer (score 2):

Check if the cookie exists as a first step in `run`

```
app.run(function($route, $rootScope, $http, $location, $cookieStore, $anchorScroll) {
    var user = $cookieStore.get('user');
        if (user !== undefined) {
        // set up X- header and other variables here
```

Comment: Faster and better than what I was answering. Well done ;-)

Comment: Yes The user is well stored in the cookie . The problem is with $rootScope.authenticated. I'm using it to make the login page my first page loaded in my app

Comment: `app.run` takes place before the router kicks in. You can set the value of `$rootScope.authenticated` there. ps: the recommended approach would be to create a `user` service instead of using the `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to store the authentication value in the localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem ('session.authenticated', true);
```

Then you can get the authentication value as follows:

```
localStorage.getItem("session.authenticated") || false;
```